# Direction of data flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is actually meant by the direction of data flow?
Consider the composition pattern:
I have a class A, within that class A creates an instance of another class B upon instantiation of class A.
Class A holds public data accessible to both Class A and B.
Instance of class B is instantiated with data from Class A.
Instance of class B calls a method within Class A to manipulated data for Instance of Class A.

What is the data in the data flow considered as? The data held by a Class or hierarchy and permissions of Classes?
For example,
Child class should not be able to call Parent class methods on Instances of Parent class.

Comment: You may need to give a more concrete example of what your talking about.  Class A having an instantiation of class B, doesn't mean class B gains access to all the public data from Class A.  That instance of class B has no way to reference the instance of class A, unless you give it a reference.

Comment: And you may want to consider limiting your tags.  That's a pretty broad range or languages you're trying to associate this concept to

Comment: Lets say that we force the axiom, now what is considered data in data flow direction?

Comment: This isn't a theory site.  It's a concrete issue site.  If you can provide an example of a concrete issue, then it becomes less of a "too broad" question and more on topic.

Comment: Im interested more in the abstract concept rather than the imperative axioms for C++

Comment: While this _could_ be an interesting question, I tend to agree w/ @Taplar - w/o an example, it's difficult to answer-- not because it is too "abstract" but simply because the language in the question doesn't adequately describe any one scenario.

Answer (score 0):

> What is actually meant by the direction of data flow?

Let us consider a specific type of software, so that we can limit the data flow count to larger ideas.

---

There are two big divisions of data flow in telecom transport.

A.  The Transport HW carries east/west data ... from one data transport equipment to another.  Typically, this data flow is too fast for software to deal with directly, and the data flows both directions simultaneously.

B.  The telecom transport data control is called north/south data.  This flow contain 5 software data flows.  The flow is to/from the local hw, and from/to  an operation user or host.

---

There are typically 5 flows in B (telecom transport data control):

1. status_update -- software periodically reads hw status information (often once per second) and delivers the info captured to local 'fast' storage (where other commands can find it for display or delivery to host)
2. alarms-update -- very much like status update (i.e. a periodic read), but only alarms.  Alarms have duration and timeouts, and are reasonably complex.
3. pm-update -- very much like status update (i.e. a periodic read), but the software collects summary counts of specific activities ... how many bytes output, how many seconds-in-error, etc.  This also has round robin 15 minute time buckets, timeouts and other complications.
4. configuration control --  user applied commands can change the operational configuration.  The sw, in response to user command, changes specific hw config registers.  Most T1 / E1 hardware can run in either mode, and the user is required to configure each sub-system at startup.
5. provisioning control -- the user applies commands that enable (or disable) the availability of a specific hardware type to 'transport' east/west data.  (think customer billable service)

Each of these flows, from an architectural approach, may be demand-pull OR supply-push, but probably not both.

---

Example of demand-pull: status update (direction of flow is north, from hw to local storage)

On most of the systems I worked on, the status-update was triggered off the system clock, and, in a typical demand-pull, the clock event triggered a read of all the status conditions from the hw.  This collected info is typically stashed into local 'fast' storage, where other commands can find it for display or delivery to host.

---

Examples of supply-push: configuration (direction of flow is south, from user to hw)

Any config (or provisioning) command is asynchronous to the system clock (because humans don't like and are not good at syncing).  Thus, an action is triggered when the user presses the enter-key, and the supply-pushed data (command parameters)  flowed to the hardware.

For supply-push, there are sometimes coordination efforts, i.e. no config (nor prov) changes are allowed while specific other things are going on, but this is typically handled with a simple mutex.

---

Summary - at the above architectural level, the flows may seem simpler than they actually can be.

For example, sometimes, to read during a demand-pull, the software must 'tickle' some feature of the hw, and that 'tickle' feels like the 'wrong direction' ... but in this case, the 'tickle' is not part of the data flow, just overhead to accomplish the flow by extracting / pulling the data out.

Similarly, to write config data, the sw must sometimes determine if the hw will allow the change to that next configuration, and perhaps that is checked by reading from the hw.  These reads feel like the wrong direction, but again, it is not part of the data flow, just some flow overhead.

This duality happens at many levels.

---

I can't speak as much to desktop software, but I have seen demand-pull and supply-push in many places.  Perhaps somewhat less disciplined in my view point, but that is more likely about my lack of experience with large desktop applications.